# Resize image in object detection task of computer vision

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, image-preprocessing

In object detection, they usually resize by keeping the ratio the same as the original image, which usually names "letterbox" resize.

My question is:

1. Why do we need to do that? As I see with some images too long in vertical or horizontal, we will lose a lot of features in those images.
2. If it is better than normal resize, why people don't apply it in the classification task?